# Open Tab Font loses definition

Tags: bug, design

Last one for now, promise!

The font used for open tabs, and the "Reviewed-action" labels doesn't have the best definition - see the image below. There's no whitespace left in the middle of the e's, and the a's are tight up. (Technical terms, I know!) Other sites (e.g. Programmers.SE) don't have this problem - I didn't look in to how it's different.

[image]

Without wanting to ask too much, could the colour here also be reconsidered? It *just* mismatches the main site link colour.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Update

I've updated the font for tabs and filter tabs to a similar, but different font that should render better at bold. This issue should be corrected now. Thanks!

---

Thanks for reporting the issue. Unfortunately the issue with closed counters is a result of the font, font-weight, color and screen rendering. I updated the color to not be a bright purple. Let's see if that fixes the issue. Here's an example of what's being built in the next production build:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just spotted it's already live. Colour change is nice, but still got the closed counters. If it's screen rendering, I might have to grin and bear it, but surely this is how it looks to anyone not in retina-world?

Comment: @Chris Yep, I see the same as you (e's with no interior whitespace, etc.) in 1920x1080 at default zoom and DPI in the latest Chrome, the latest Firefox, and Microsoft Edge.  Interestingly, I *don't* see it in IE 11 -- it looks like it is using a default font instead.

Comment: @Hynes - new font is much better on the tabs! Still looks like it's using the old font on the "Leave Open"/"Approve" etc. badges on http://music.stackexchange.com/users/10938/chris?tab=activity however. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately those highlights aren't normally something we modify. If continues to be a problem, let me know and I'll bring it up with the team. Thanks.

Comment: @Hynes: Ok. Didn't realise it was just bolded-main-site-font - thought it was already a different font. Wouldn't say it's causing me a problem, just looks a little messy to me. Thanks for looking in to it!